# Java Runtime query - toString() and T

Tags: java

In the following expression:

```
T(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils).toString(T(java.lang.Runtime)
   .getRuntime().exec(T(java.lang.Character).toString(105)
   .concat(T(java.lang.Character).toString(100))).getInputStream())
```

Does the '105' in `toString(105)` refer to an itemized object within the Character class?

and

Why is the 'T', which I believe expresses a generic type, and is used 4 times in this expression, a necessary feature of Java?

Comment: Please try to enclose your code within triple back ticks. Something like this: ``` {new_line} some_code {new_line} ```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid Java code... where did you get this? Please provide more context.

Comment: Hi Jon, if the code snippet is placed within {} as a search query on a search website, preceded by * or ? or # of course,  it DOES provide information regarding that server, for example details of the user running the server. It definitely works, but I need to understand what the code is actually doing.

Comment: **Java**: `T()` could be a method call, but `T(java.lang.Runtime)` is invalid since there is no class `java.lang` from which `Runtime` could be a member | `toString(105)` is calling the `toString(int)` method that returns the string representation of given integer: `"105"`  || maybe the question should not be tagged (only) with the [tag:java] tag... (this comment was written before reading previous one - no idea what mentioned site does with its input)

Comment: in that query (just guessing) `T(java.lang.Character)` could mean the class (**T**ype) `java.lang.Character` - `T(java.lang.Character).toString(105)` would be `Character.toString(105)` (reuslting in `"i"`), same for `100` (`"d"`) - so basically it looks like it is trying to execute  `IOUtils.toString(Runtime.getRuntime.exec("id").getInputStream())` || so `T()` in that (unknown to me) query language PROBABLY means the class given by its argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` method that seems to be invoked here is actually the `toString(char)` (static) method of `java.lang.Character`. Quoting the documentation:

```
public static String toString(char c)

Returns a String object representing the specified char.
The result is a string of length 1 consisting solely of the specified char.

Parameters:
    c - the char to be converted
Returns:
    the string representation of the specified char
Since:
    1.4
```

Note that 100 and 105 are also valid `char` values where `100 == 'd'` and `105 == 'i'`.

**Update:** after knowing the context, I am now confident that this code is intended to be injected into a template for a web page. The template engine used provides special syntax for accessing static methods where `T(Classname)` resolves to just `Classname` (not `Classname.class`!) in the resulting Java code.

So your code would be translated to:

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(java.lang.Runtime
   .getRuntime().exec(java.lang.Character.toString(105)
   .concat(java.lang.Character.toString(100))).getInputStream())
```

The full qualification of the class names is necessary because we do not know if those classes are imported on the attacked site (or if the template engine even allows imports or class names must always be fully qualified).

A more readable version of the code that assumes imports is

```
IOUtils.toString(
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        Character.toString(105).concat(Character.toString(100))
    ).getInputStream()
)
```

And after a little de-obfuscation...

```
IOUtils.toString(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("id").getInputStream())
```

Comment: Thank you so much UniverseE. Your explanation tells me that this code snippet, if placed between {} and preceded by a * or # or $, could be entered into a search bar on a search website running on Java in order to maliciously 'id' the user running the server!  Any idea why the T's are essential in the expression?

Comment: I would assume that the website under attack is using some sort of template engine which has special syntax where `T(Classname)` means just `Classname` in normal Java Code. So the `T` does not stand for a generic type here, but is just special syntax for telling the template engine that the following argument is a class name. So `T(java.lang.Character).toString(100)` would be just `java.lang.Character.toString(100)` in normal Java code.

Comment: @rdre8 okay, I added that aspect to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Whatever this is, it is definitely NOT meaningful Java code.

And the fact that you can provide it as as a search query on some site is not evidence that it is Java either.

I suspect that this is actually some custom (site-specific?) query language.  That makes it futile to try to understand it as a Java snippet.

Your theory that `T` could denote a generic type parameter doesn't work.  Java would not allow you to write `T(...)` if that was the case.

Furthermore, if we assume that `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`, `java.lang.Runtime` and so on are intended to refer to Java class objects, then the correct Java syntax would be `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.class`, `java.lang.Runtime.class` and so on.

---

So what *does* it mean?

Well a bit of Googling found me some other examples that look like yours.   For instance;

- https://github.com/VikasVarshney/ssti-payload

appears to generate "code" that is reminiscent of your example.  This is SSTI - Server Side Template Injection, and it appears to be targeting Java EE Expression Language (EL).

And I think this particular example is an attempt to run the Linux `id` program ... which would output some basic information about the  user and group ids for the account running your web server.

Does it matter?  Well only if your site is vulnerable to SSTI attacks!

How would you know if your site is vulnerable?

- By understanding the nature of SSTI with respect to EL and other potential attack vectors ... and auditing your codebase and configurations.
- By using a vulnerability scanner to test your site and/or your code-base.
- By employing the services of a trustworthy IT security company to do some penetration testing.

In this case, you could also try to use `curl` to repeat the attempted attack ... as the hacker would have done ... based on what is in your logs.  Just see if it actually works.  Note that running the `id` program does no actual damage to your system.  The harm would be in the information that is leaked to a hacker ... if they succeed.

Note that if this hack did succeed, then the hacker would probably try to run other programs.  These *could* do some damage to your system, depending on how how well your server was hardened against such things.